# Javascript Faceted Search Client (Framework)

Tags: javascript, ajax, frameworks, solr, facet

I wonder if there's any javascript framework (client-side stuff) to manage search results UI in a facet-based way (with facet generation, counting for items matching that facet..).

In other words, something like Ajax Solr (the old SolrJS), but not based on Solr :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: don't understand the question ... facet needs to be calculated from the search engine ... do you really want a pure js search engine? I doubt it. but ... jsii is something like this ... without (facet) support ;) you are welcome to contribute of course!! https://github.com/karussell/jsii

Comment: @Karussell Maybe the question is bad-written, my fault obviously :)
I mean an UI interface to manage experience of a facet based engine :)

Comment: @Karussell Your project jsii seems to be a nice idea, congrats!

Comment: what do you want to achieve? do you want to display data (with facets) which does not come from solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simile Exhibhit](http://www.simile-widgets.org/wiki/Main_Page) seems to fit your description. Have you tried that before?

Comment: Never tried, but it seems close to what i was looking for. I'll give it a try, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at this implementation of [faceted search in javascript](http://eikes.github.com/facetedsearch/).