# AJAX update category - category - product on Homepage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I need to create, I think, something quite complicated and was wondering if some people could help me out with ideas/tutorials/examples.

The thing is our client wants a step-by-step-system on the homepage where the customer can already choose between different categories and then view the asociated products. 
Yes I know about Layered Navigation and AJAX stuff by Amasty etc but I don’t think thats what I need in this situation. Let me explain step by step.

First off, it’s a phone repair shop.

The section consists of 4 columns, each column should update according to what you have choosen before that one. 
The first column consists of the main categories (brands of phones) if you choose lets say HTC then the second column should show the subcategories of HTC. Then after youve choosen a type of phone the third column should update with the possible repairs (the products). Then after choosing one of the repairs(products) the fourth column should update with the price etc and show you the ‘Proceed to checkout’ button. 
All these updates should occur using AJAX obviously because constantly reloading the page is an annoyance.

Im quite familiar with Magento’s structure, I think I know enough to create my own module and my knowledge of PHP and jQuery/Javascript should be sufficient. But I have no idea where to start and how complicated this is. Because we have a set development time Im not sure I can do this within the limits of agreed time.

Hope anyone could share some insights and ideas!

The Netherlands (hence the possible grammar errors :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function loadFilter(variable1,variable2,option,div){
    $.post("../filtros.php",
       data:{  variable1:var1,  variable2:var2,  option:option},
       function(data){
                 $("#"+ div+"").html(data);
             }
         );
     }
       $("#var1").click(function(){
            loadFilter($(this).val(),"","option1","div1");
       });
       $("#var2").click(function(){
           loadFilter($("#var1").val(),$(this).val(),"option2","div2");
});`

And php(../filtros.php)

```
$option=$_REQUEST["option"];
if($option=="var1"){ 
   $query = "select * from yourtable where var1 =". $_REQUEST["var1"];
}
if($option=="var2"){ 
   $query = "select * from yourtable where var1 =". $_REQUEST["var1"].
"and var2 = ".$_REQUEST["var2"];
}
foreach(query as q){
    echo q;
}
```

when click on #var1 load its data(var2)

and click on #var2 load its data

Comment: Even though this isn't exactly as I figured it out. This is the general answer that set me in the right direction. I created my own module to handle my AjaxRequests using a custom IndexController.php and having a few public functions that returned the needed html.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just make an ajax request function for every part of the webpage you want to update. You can send the response text to a callback function which will build up the column

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a "Faceted Search".  Searching the web for that exact phrase should yield some pretty good results.  I did that and came across [this GitHub project](https://github.com/eikes/facetedsearch).  It has a nice [example page](http://eikes.github.io/facetedsearch/) and you should be able to read through it's source code for some tips.  Some other people have asked similar questions, so this question might be flagged as a *duplicate*.  Take a look at [other StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22faceted%20search%22%20%5Bjavascript%5D), this one might be helpful: [Javascript Faceted Search Client (Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821751/javascript-faceted-search-client-framework)

Good luck.